# discoveryutil: command not found

Tags: dns

After connecting VPN, I often have to flush DNS to get my private hosts to be found. I would do this

`sudo discoveryutil mdnsflushcache; sudo discoveryutil udnsflushcaches`

Now, after upgrading to Yosemite 10.10.4, I get

`sudo: discoveryutil: command not found`

So, `discoveryutil` is gone in 10.10.4? How can I flush DNS now?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since discoveryutil was replaced by its predecessor mDNSResponder in 10.10.4 use `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` again (like in Lion/Mountain Lion/Mavericks) to flush the DNS cache.

Answer (score 2):

A colleague has suggested `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache`. The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dscacheutil.1.html) states

> dscacheutil -- gather information, statistics and initiate queries
>   to the Directory Service cache.
>
> -flushcache
>                 Flushes the entire cache.  This should only be used in extreme cases.  Validation information
>                 is used within the cache along with other techniques to ensure the OS has valid information
>                 available to it.

Comment: Discovery util is missing..... That's what the original post said.

Comment: this answer suggests `dscacheutil` not `discoveryutil`. also, check out the author of this question and of the original post...and this comment.